# How do set a range of cells to show the accuracy of the data automatically?

Tags: significant-digits

I was looking for a simple solution such as conditional formatting rules, but I can't find a way.

I need a range of cells say a column of numbers to automatically adjust the accuracy (number of number after the decimal) based solely on the number/data that is copied into the cells.

Labs provide results with accuracy based on varying factors that can change over time depending on the analysis machines used, the amount of sample provided, etc.  So one may get the following column of results (typically no more than 4 places of decimal).

2.0,
0.11,
6.126,
100.0001

You can't just set the column to show 4 places of decimal as this is an error.
(i.e. 2.0 is not the same as 2.0000.  The latter implies you are accurate to the 4th decimal as opposed to the level of accuracy the lab supplied which is only accurate to the 1st decimal.  This is referred to as significant digits.)

So the issue is how do I copy and past the above data into a workbook and have it automatically show the exact data with the number of decimals as shown/input without rounding or adding significant digits?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This custom formatting should do it

0.0###

to do this

1. Select the range of cells you want the formatting applied to
2. Under Formatting drop-down select "Number Formatting"
3. Open the formatting drop-down again and select "More Number Formats"
4. On the window that pops up, on the left side select "Custom"
5. Then on the box that says "Type:" type the format string "0.0###"
6. Then click ok, now on the format drop down the word "Custom" should be visible